# How to Substitute Variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below Oracle query inserts data into table by substituting variables. How I achieve the same in PostgreSQL?

```
INSERT INTO control_threshold (threshold_id, group_name, description, sql, low_value, high_value)
VALUES(threshold_seq.nextval, '&2', '&1',  TRIM('&5' || '&6' || '&7' || '&8' || '&9'),
trim('&3'), trim('&4'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tool that's closest to SQL Developer is pgAdmin, which is usually installed alongside PostgreSQL.  But it doesn't have the same feature set.

To substitute parameters like that in pgAdmin, I think you'll have to write a stored procedure.

In [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), the PostgreSQL command-line client, you can set variables, and you can use them in a SQL query.

```
sandbox=# \set this_year 2014
sandbox=# select cal_date
sandbox-# from calendar
sandbox-# where year_of_date = :this_year   -- Variable substitution
sandbox-# order by cal_date;
```

```
  cal_date  
------------
 2014-01-01
 2014-01-02
 2014-01-03
 2014-01-04
 2014-01-05
 2014-01-06
 2014-01-07
...
```

In psql, you can set variables with the `\set` meta-command, or you can set them on the command line with `-v assignment`, `--set=assignment`, or `--variable=assignment`.

Comment: Actually SQL Developer allows connections to Postgres as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I didn't know that. Thanks! I'm about to develop a new entry on my CV . . .

Comment: Thanks. I did figure this out yesterday but had to wait for 8 hrs before I was allowed to post my answer.